# Why is Safari recommended for downloading MacTeX?

Tags: installing, mac, mactex

I have a MacBook Pro and I want to update my Tex Live.
The [MacTeX download page](https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) is *strongly* recommending to use Safari.

I had a problem with my Safari a few days back and now I am using Chrome as a browser.
Is it OK to go ahead with the installation?
I am not a very tech person so didn't want to mess up here.

update:

[image]

I have installed it. Now what should i do next? Will my TexMaker identify it automatically?Now when I run my TexMaker I see following in my log file

[image]

So my version has been updated. right? And so I should be following standard procedure to add citation sin my beamer presentation.

Comment: I don't use Safari. Maybe Safari can resume downloads. Since the file is quite big, if you loose Internet connection... But go on and just download the file.

Comment: As @krnk suggests, you can use the process detailed in the [FAQ](http://www.tug.org/mactex/faq/#qm01) to see if the download went fine. If it did, you should not have any troubles with it.

Comment: Safari works better with large files. You can't do anything wrong if you continue with chrome. If it doesn't work, use safari just for the download.

Comment: Have you tried TeXMaker to see? Wouldn't that be quicker? But, yes, since it relies on symbolic links, it should be fine. Use the Preference Pane MacTeX installs to double-check which edition is active if in doubt.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Safari is recommended as experience from a range of users suggests it has fewer issues with the download than other browsers. However, there is nothing to preclude downloading with Chrome, Firefox or even `curl`. Try with your favoured browser and if this leads to a corrupt download then try Safari. (Or of course if your favoured browser is Safari, use that and report any issues to the [TeX on Mac OS](http://mactex-wiki.tug.org/wiki/index.php?title=TeX_on_Mac_OS_X_mailing_list) mailing list.)

Comment: pssst.. in OSX, instead of `wget`, one would use `curl` as it comes shipped-in.

Comment: @morbusg Corrected (it's CW anyway ...): I've not tried either, just assumed that being Unix-based there would be `wget` - obviously I was wrong